# Can I put from:email different from my domain when sending email?

Tags: php, email

I have a contact form on my website, where user puts his email and question. Then this info is sent to my email.

Am I allowed to put user email in `$email->from()`, when sending the contact email to my own support, so that I could directly reply from the email client? Or will I be penalized for using the email that does not belong to my domain?

Right now I am putting my standard email (`support@***.**`) so I can't use the 'Reply' Button.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

Comment: you can change to email as you want.

Comment: yes, but so do spammers so ..

Comment: You can add 'reply-to' instead of from.

Comment: Ideally, you should set up at least [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) for your domain. This will tell people *which* email servers are allowed to send for that domain, which helps especially if the domain part in the email address is different from the server actually sending the email. DKIM is also an option, but more work to set up (SPF will take just a few minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bouncing off of the comment by @ryantxr try the `additional_headers` option of PHP's `mail()` function ([php manual link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3898))

The copy-paste version for posterity is below.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It's worth noting that the `$headers` variable is NOT an array but a string with newlines.

Comment: I just did not know about reply-to option. I am using swift mailer and it has that option to use easily. :)

Comment: Also worth noting if "From" domain doesn't match the domain sent from some/most/all spam filters will bounce it. Reply-To is fine.